# woocommerce calculate shipping not working

Tags: woocommerce

I successfully get an array of shipping packages from:

```
$mypackages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();  
print_r($mypackages);
```

However this doesn't return the rates for shipping.  So after researching i added the following:

```
$mypackages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();  
$mypackages = WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping($mypackages);
print_r($mypackages);
```

Now nothing is returned.  I have tried `WC()->shipping->get_packages();` but a blank array is returned.  However, my checkout is fine it displays shipping methods.

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by doing the following..

```
define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CART', true );

WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
```

$packages array is now successfully returned.

Comment: Any idea why i get  Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! when trying your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found that with WC 3 the get_packages() method works fine.  However with WC version 2, the get_packages when called when doing AJAX, would not load the data.  So, to make code that would work with all versions, I have used:

```
    global $woocommerce;
    if (version_compare($woocommerce->version, "3.0.0", "<") && defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) {
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
        WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
    }
    $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
```

This worked for me with WC version 3 and 2 with and without AJAX.  By the way, this was tested with WC versions 2.6.14 and the latest 3.4.3 (at the time of posting) versions.

Comment: Please edit code in your answer. Format is as code block.